# I need JS code of creating text select and share button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a `Select` and `Share` button by following an example. I added only twitter and WhatsApp options for now. But the problem is that whenever I add the js code function for `whatsappShareBtn`, none of the buttons works and after removing it, `twitterShareBtn` works fine.

```js
const selectableTextArea = document.querySelectorAll(".selectable-text-area");
const twitterShareBtn = document.querySelector("#twitter-share-btn");
const whatsappShareBtn = document.querySelector("#whatsapp-share-btn");

selectableTextArea.forEach(elem => {
  elem.addEventListener("mouseup", selectableTextAreaMouseUp);
});

twitterShareBtn.addEventListener("click", twitterShareBtnClick);
whatsappShareBtn.addEventListener("click", whatsappShareBtnClick);

document.addEventListener("mousedown", documentMouseDown);

function selectableTextAreaMouseUp(event) {
  setTimeout(() => { // In order to avoid some weird behavior...
    const selectedText = window.getSelection().toString().trim();
    if (selectedText.length) {
      const x = event.pageX;
      const y = event.pageY;
      const twitterShareBtnWidth = Number(getComputedStyle(twitterShareBtn).width.slice(0, -2));
      const twitterShareBtnHeight = Number(getComputedStyle(twitterShareBtn).height.slice(0, -2));
      const whatsappShareBtnWidth = Number(getComputedStyle(whatsappShareBtn).width.slice(0, -2));
      const whatsappShareBtnHeight = Number(getComputedStyle(whatsappShareBtn).height.slice(0, -2));

      if (document.activeElement !== twitterShareBtn) {
        twitterShareBtn.style.left = `${x - twitterShareBtnWidth*0.5}px`;
        twitterShareBtn.style.top = `${y - twitterShareBtnHeight*1.25}px`;
        twitterShareBtn.style.display = "block";
        twitterShareBtn.classList.add("btnEntrance");
      } else {
        twitterShareBtn.style.left = `${x-twitterShareBtnWidth*0.5}px`;
        twitterShareBtn.style.top = `${y-twitterShareBtnHeight*0.5}px`;
      }

      if (document.activeElement !== whatsappShareBtn) {
        whatsappShareBtn.style.left = `${x - whatsappShareBtnWidth*1.50}px`;
        whatsappShareBtn.style.top = `${y - whatsappShareBtnHeight*1.25}px`;
        whatsappShareBtn.style.display = "block";
        whatsappShareBtn.classList.add("btnEntrance");
      } else {
        whatsappShareBtn.style.left = `${x-whatsappShareBtnWidth*0.5}px`;
        whatsappShareBtn.style.top = `${y-whatsappShareBtnHeight*0.5}px`;
      }
    }
  }, 0);
}

function documentMouseDown(event) {
  if (event.target.id !== "twitter-share-btn" && getComputedStyle(twitterShareBtn).display === "block") {
    twitterShareBtn.style.display = "none";
    twitterShareBtn.classList.remove("btnEntrance");
    window.getSelection().empty();
  }

  if (event.target.id !== "whatsapp-share-btn" && getComputedStyle(whatsappShareBtn).display === "block") {
    whatsappShareBtn.style.display = "none";
    whatsappShareBtn.classList.remove("btnEntrance");
    window.getSelection().empty();
  }
}

function twitterShareBtnClick(event) {
  const selectedText = window.getSelection().toString().trim();
  if (selectedText.length) {
    // General Twitter Share URL: https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text={title}&url={url}&hashtags={hash_tags}&via={user_id}
    const twitterShareUrl = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet";
    const text = `${encodeURIComponent(selectedText)}`;
    const currentUrl = encodeURIComponent(window.location.href);
    const hashtags = "helloworld, test, testing";
    const via = "CodingJrney";
    window.open(`${twitterShareUrl}?text="${text}"&url=${currentUrl}&hashtags=${hashtags}&via=${via}`);

  }
}

function whatsappShareBtnClick(event) {
  const selectedText1 = window.getSelection().toString().trim();
  if (selectedText1.length) {
    const whatsappShareUrl = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send";
    const text = `${encodeURIComponent(selectedText1)}`;
    window.open(`${whatsappShareUrl}?text="${text}"`);
  }

}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

.container {
  padding: 1.5rem 10rem;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin: 1.25rem 0;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

hr {
  margin: 3rem 0;
  border: 0;
  height: 1px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25));
}

p {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  line-height: 1.75rem;
}


/* =============================== DEFAULT*/

#twitter-share-btn {
  width: 40px;
  height: 2.5rem;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid #868686;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  display: none;
  transition: color 0.2s, background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

#twitter-share-btn:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #56b8f5;
}

#twitter-share-btn i {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.btnEntrance {
  animation-duration: 0.2s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-name: btnEntrance;
}

#whatsapp-share-btn {
  width: 40px;
  height: 2.5rem;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid #868686;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  display: none;
  transition: color 0.2s, background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

#whatsapp-share-btn:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #56b8f5;
}

#whatsapp-share-btn i {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.btnEntrance {
  animation-duration: 0.2s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-name: btnEntrance;
}

@keyframes btnEntrance {
  /* zoomIn */
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale3d(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    padding: 1.25rem 6rem;
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
  }
  h2 {
    font-size: 1.75rem;
  }
}

@media(max-width:768px) {
  html {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  .container {
    padding: 1rem 3rem;
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
  h2 {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
  hr {
    margin: 1.5rem 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Conquering Responsive Layouts</title>
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> -->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <!-- <script src="nav.js"></script> -->

</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="selectable-text-area">

      <h1>A Visual Type Scale</h1>
      <p>What looked like a small patch of purple grass, above five feet square, was moving across the sand in their direction.</p>
      <p>When it came near enough he perceived that it was not grass; there were no blades, but only purple roots. The roots were revolving, for each small plant in the whole patch, like the spokes of a rimless wheel.</p>
      <h2>A Visual Type Scale</h2>
      <p>What looked like a small patch of purple grass, above five feet square, was moving across the sand in their direction.</p>
      <p>When it came near enough he perceived that it was not grass; there were no blades, but only purple roots. The roots were revolving, for each small plant in the whole patch, like the spokes of a rimless wheel.</p>
      <h3>A Visual Type Scale</h3>
      <p>What looked like a small patch of purple grass, above five feet square, was moving across the sand in their direction.</p>
      <p>When it came near enough he perceived that it was not grass; there were no blades, but only purple roots. The roots were revolving, for each small plant in the whole patch, like the spokes of a rimless wheel.</p>
      <h4>A Visual Type Scale</h4>
      <p>What looked like a small patch of purple grass, above five feet square, was moving across the sand in their direction.</p>
      <p>When it came near enough he perceived that it was not grass; there were no blades, but only purple roots. The roots were revolving, for each small plant in the whole patch, like the spokes of a rimless wheel.</p>
      <h5>A Visual Type Scale</h5>
      <p>What looked like a small patch of purple grass, above five feet square, was moving across the sand in their direction.</p>
      <p>When it came near enough he perceived that it was not grass; there were no blades, but only purple roots. The roots were revolving, for each small plant in the whole patch, like the spokes of a rimless wheel.</p>
      <p>— Excerpt from A Voyage to Arcturus, by David Lindsay.</p>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="button">

    <button id="twitter-share-btn"> W </button>
    <button id="whatsapp-share-btn"> T </button>

  </div>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/OwO1234/pen/JjLWJPL

Comment: The Problem is with **CSS** not with **JS**. You've set same properties for WhatsApp and Twitter buttons. Try changing one of this properties `z-index`, `top` , `left` . But since your problem is mainly with `z-index` you should change the `top` and `left` properties of buttons